# How to add labels combined with values in tmaps labels

Tags: r, label, maps

I want to add both country labels with their respective data in tmaps. I know that tm_text allows me to add labels like this (I know the output looks terrible, but is just to illustrate):

```
data("World")

tm_shape(World)+
  tm_borders()+ 
  tm_fill("HPI",
          palette = "Blues")+
  tm_text("pop_est")
```

I want each label to be something like this:  "country name" ":" "variable". And I tried with paste0:

```
tm_shape(World)+
  tm_borders()+ 
  tm_fill("HPI",
          palette = "Blues")+
  tm_text(paste0("pop_est", ":", "HPI"))

Error: Incorrect data variable used for the text
```

Does anybody knows how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting the error because the tm_text is expecting a character input (which then is used as a column name behind the scenes). The problem is that the result of paste() or paste0() is a string itself but but it is not an existing column.

The solution is to generate a new column of the desired text and use this as input for tm_text.

```
library(tmap)

World$text <- paste0(World$pop_est, ":", World$HPI)
tm_shape(World)+
  tm_borders()+ 
  tm_fill("HPI",
          palette = "Blues")+
  tm_text("text")
```

As you said, the output is ugly, therefore I will not include it.